# about importing js module named as 'url'

Tags: javascript, module

This is some part of my code.

```
import { URL } from './url.js'

let imageurl = URL.join(globalBaseUrl, location)
```

`URL` is an object written on url.js which is located in my src folder.

I know there already exists object of same name in global scope, but I cannot find any better name so I decided to keep the name.

when I wrote code first, I found that caller file cannot load `URL` module properly. By trial and error, I found that only the code above works. some `inport` statement like `import URL from './url'` or `import { URL } from 'url'` could not load module. only `import { URL } from './url'` (it seems that extension does not matter) works in my environment.

I'm not sure whether this is intended or some bug of webpack or something. Why does this happen?

Comment: What exactly does `url.js` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import URL from './url'
```

will import the default import. If it does not have a default import, it won't work.

named import use the second syntax.

```
import { URL } from 'url'
```

Unless you've tinkered with your webpack config, this syntax is used to get the default import from a node_modules named url.